# NullPointerException when calling Redis method

Tags: scala, redis

I am trying to check for a key in a Redis database with the `exists` method:

```
redis.exists(searchuid)
```

but I get the following error

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `redis` or `searchuid` is *null*.